# jQuery select2-offscreen class with drop list?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc-4

I am making a small project with MVC4, C#, Razor Engine and jQuery. In my code I have a drop list, and every time an item is selected in that drop list I want to send an Ajax request with the information selected, plus the id of an order that is in the HTML:

```
<input type="hidden" id="materialRequestId" value=@myId />
```

To achieve this, when a user selects an item in my drop list, I try to get the `closest/sibling/find` HTML tag by using its id, but I am failing because `$(this)` seems to have only a class of `select2-offscreen` and thus everytime I use one of the previous jQuery functions, I get undefined.

```
$('#OfficeId').change(function () {
    alert($(this).closest("div").siblings("#materialRequestId").value;);         
});
```

This is my HTML:

```
<td>
    <input type="hidden" id="materialRequestId" value=4 />
    <div class="hide officeList">
        <select id="OfficeId" name="OfficeId">
            <option value="18">AMAALB</option>
            <option value="19">AMABGR</option>
            <option value="20">AMACRO</option>
        </select>
   </div>
</td>
```

What am I missing here? Why is this not working?

Comment: can you not just get the value direct instead ? `$("#materialRequestId").value;`

Comment: I can, but the problem is that I have multiple entities with that id. Now that I come to think about it, it should actually be a class instead of an Id, but the problem remains xD

Comment: no more than 1 element on a page can have that id.

Comment: Ya, got it !
Thanks!
Also, I tried using `.attr('value')` in the code and it works ! Have no idea why :S

If you add an answer with this explaination, I will accept it :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you get the value direct

```
 $("#materialRequestId").attr("value");
```

And make sure that only 1 element per page has that unique id it should work

Comment: actually, `$("#materialRequestId").attr('value')` also works. Know why?

Comment: You're right, because you're going for the attribute,I've left that off the code..d'oh.Edited now. It should be attr('value');

Comment: Or even simpler, `$("#materialRequestId").val();`